# Python Script doesn't work with certain filenames

Tags: python, nameerror

I have a script which does the following: If there is a file that ends with 'Kobo.xlsx' in the same directory as the script, it reads the file, makes some changes to it, defines a 'new_filename' from the name of the file, and spits out a new .xlsx with the new filename. Here is the code:

```
## Get path of Script ##

abspath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)
os.chdir(dname)
files = os.listdir(dname) 
for file in files:
    if file.endswith('Kobo.xlsx'):
    
        ## Define New Filename ##
    
        filename = os.path.basename(file)
        size = len(filename)
        new_filename = (filename[:size - 9]) + "Sorted.xlsx"

        ## Pandas Things ... ##

    #### Exporting ####

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(new_filename, engine='xlsxwriter')
    writer.save()
```

Sometimes when I run the script, I get the following error:

```
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(new_filename, engine='xlsxwriter')
NameError: name 'new_filename' is not defined
```

Sometimes when I run the script, I don't. It seems the error only comes up for certain filenames (different directories don't matter). However, If I go through the command prompt to get the new filename, it works in both cases (for the filename that the script worked with, and that the script didn't work with).

How do I avoid the error indefinitely? Thanks in advance - sorry if it's a silly question.

Comment: The code that writes the new file should be inside the `if`.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. I immediately see a path through your code that would leave new_filename unset. You should add some debugging output to your script and see under what conditions you don't run the code inside the `if` block

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do the write unless you already did the read, so those last two lines need to be indented to be part of the `if` statement.  If the very first file you read does not end in `Kobo.xlsx`, then you'll try to do the write, but the variable `new_filename` was never created.

Comment: Thanks Tim, you're the best. What a funny thing to overlook.